# How to use OUT parameter values returned from METHOD.INVOKE in C#

Tags: c#

I am using C# 2.0,

I am trying to call webmethod of my webservice, please see below code sample:

```
    try
    {

        Type objtype = Type.GetType(crisresult.ToString());
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objtype);

        Object[] mArgs = new Object[methodArgs.Length + 1];
        methodArgs.CopyTo(mArgs, 0);
        mArgs.SetValue(obj, methodArgs.Length);
        methodArgs = mArgs;

        Object result = mi.Invoke(service, methodArgs);

        JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());

        // option 1) if you are just using primitives
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in parsed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }      
    }
```

Now in above code in my `methodArgs` object array is having an out parameter(crisresult), now incase of any error returned from my webservice method `Object result = mi.Invoke(service, methodArgs);` is shown in my out parameter, I am sure that my out parameter is the last object in my `methodArgs`object array, I am looking to get that object and check for the error result returned from the webservice.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `methodArgs` will have been updated to account for any `ref` / `out` parameters. Since you believe it is the last one:

```
object foo = methodArgs[methodArgs.Length-1];
```

Comment: Thanks @ Marc, then how to read any property of the Object "foo", say I have a property by name "message" in it, how to read the value of "message" property

Comment: In 4.0, `((dynamic)foo).message`; in 2.0 - `foo.GetType().GetProperty("message").GetValue(foo,null)`